# How to add Order by in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
update Room set Status = case
                        when Room_Rev.In_DateTime IS NOT NULL and Room_Rev.Out_DateTime IS NULL
                            then 'U'
                        when Room_Rev.In_DateTime IS NOT NULL and Room_Rev.Out_DateTime IS NOT NULL
                            then 'A'     
                        when Room.Status!='R' and Room.Status!='U' and Room.Status!='A'
                            then Room.Status
                         else 'R'
                                end 
                                FROM Room JOIN Room_Rev 
                    ON Room.Room_ID=Room_Rev.Room_ID 
                    and 
                    ((Room_Rev.Start_Date >= '2015-03-22' and Room_Rev.End_Date <= '2015-03-22') 
                                OR 
                    (Room_Rev.Start_Date<= '2015-03-22' and Room_Rev.End_Date> '2015-03-22') 
                                OR 
                    (Room_Rev.Start_Date< '2015-03-22' and Room_Rev.End_Date>= '2015-03-22'))
```

How to add order by Rev_ID desc in the query?
There are two table which is Room and Room_Rev,
they are one to many relationship

[image: Room_Rev table]
The last two row ROM0006 already fill the In_DateTime and Out_DateTime,
thus it regard check out,
and the last row insert new reservation,
the In_DateTime is null
thus i need the query return 'R' (Reserved status)

Comment: is this really the **Microsoft** SQL server? if so, which version?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to get thr room status by compare the start date and out date, then update the Room table

Comment: Room_Rev record the reservation detail which link with Reservation table and Room table

Comment: You can not use order by clause in update statement. What can orderring give you here?

Comment: `UPDATE` just updates all rows that match the `WHERE` criteria - there's really no need or no benefit from *ordering* anything...... in SQL Server, therefore, `UPDATE` **does not** support any `ORDER BY` ...

Comment: question already update by insert table

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to enforce order on your update (or insert). You enforce the order on your SELECT query when you're reading the data back out.

Comment: I think I got the OP's idea. He is not trying to influence UPDATE order. He has one-to-many relation between ROOM and Room_Rev, resulting in uncertainty of final ROOM.status because it is influenced by records in Room_Rev which may have multiple records for each record in ROOM. He needs some aggregation over ROOM.Room_ID in Room_Rev. At current moment I think T-SQL via `cursor` would allow to create most clear code for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the possible solutions I suggest a nested query instead of a join in UPDATE statement. The logic of the update is not completely clear to me, so I leave the final update for OP to correct order of sorting (Note I used `top 1` and `order by room_ID` in the nested SELECT statement). However, this approach allows to handle all usual techniques applicable for a SELECT.

```
update Room set Status = (select TOP 1 case
        when Room_Rev.In_DateTime IS NOT NULL and Room_Rev.Out_DateTime IS NULL
            then 'U'
        when Room_Rev.In_DateTime IS NOT NULL and Room_Rev.Out_DateTime IS NOT NULL
            then 'A'     
        when Room.Status!='R' and Room.Status!='U' and Room.Status!='A'
            then Room.Status
            else 'R'
        end 
    FROM Room_Rev 
    WHERE Room.Room_ID=Room_Rev.Room_ID 
    and 
    ((Room_Rev.Start_Date >= '2015-03-22' and Room_Rev.End_Date <= '2015-03-22') 
                OR 
    (Room_Rev.Start_Date<= '2015-03-22' and Room_Rev.End_Date> '2015-03-22') 
                OR 
    (Room_Rev.Start_Date< '2015-03-22' and Room_Rev.End_Date>= '2015-03-22'))
    ORDER BY Room_Rev.Room_Id
    )
```

PS. As a piece of advise I still assume that such approach is not valid. It prevents proper normalization of data. You'd rather have this information always queried dynamically when required, instead of writing static value to ROOM.status